# Second-order differential equation with substitution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to do this (it's from an advanced calculus past paper at university). I can't see where to go after the hinted substitution. I've not used this forum much; If I've failed to find a similar example here, please suggest how to search and find it. Question:

Find the solution of the second-order differential equation

$$ y \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 - y^4 = 0$$

subject to the conditions $ \quad y(0)=1\quad and \quad y'(0)=0 $

Hint: Let $ p=\frac{dy}{dx} $ and $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = p \ \frac{dp}{dy} $